# How to save image from a picture box which contains dynamically created buttons on it in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have created dynamically created picture box and I have added some dynamically created buttons on. When i try to save it gives me.

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

My code is as following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // PB.Image.Save("C:\\Users\\ISHTIAQ RANA\\Desktop\\mywork");
   SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
   f.Filter = "JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg";
   if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       // File.Save(f.FileName);
       PB.Image.Save(f.FileName);
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe that there are something wrong with your `PB`. Are you sure you have already initialized your picture box before `PB.Image.Save(f.FileName);`

Comment: i initialize it with this .

Comment: PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();

Comment: on an other button click i use

Comment: sh = Convert.ToInt16(txtHeightPanel.Text);
            sw = Convert.ToInt16(txtWidthPanel.Text);

            PB.Height = sh;
            PB.Width = sw;
            PB.BackColor = Color.White;
            PB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            this.panel1.Controls.Add(PB);

Comment: You can update your question by providing more relevant code, it will be useful for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did you debug the code and see if `PB` is not null?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't set the PictureBox Image to anything.  It is the image that has not been set to an instance of an object.  you could put the following code at the beginning of your button1_Click event to verify this.

```
if (PB == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("PictureBox not set to an instance of an object.");
    return;
}
if (PB.Image == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Image not set to an instance of an object.");
    return;
}
```